# Event Handling on a Jetpack Compose Card

Tags: android, kotlin, event-handling, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-card

I have a music player app - on my screen, I have cards displaying information about tracks. When I tap on one card, the player should play its track.

```
@Composable
fun TrackCard(track: Track) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp).fillMaxWidth(),
        contentColor = Color.Black
    ) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
            ArtistName(text = track.artist.name)
            Headline(text = track.title)
            AlbumName(text = track.album.title)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried it with adding a `Clickable` on its `Modifier` like this: `clickable(onClick = {})`
In order to let the track play, I need another param for my TrackCard, the player itself.
As I want to keep UI code separate, I was wondering if I could add an Event Listener and access play the track from there? (Also I would like to catch the different type of events like a long pressed touch etc. for different event handling as well)

The track cards get initialized like this:

```
@Composable
private fun ResultList(model: PlayerModel) {
    with(model) {
            LazyColumn(state = rememberLazyListState()) {
                items(tracks) {
                    TrackCard(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends by your MediaPlayer implementation, but you can decouple the card and the media player composables using something like:

```
val (source, setSource) = remember { mutableStateOf (
    "mediaToPlay")
}

//MediaPlayer(source)
LazyColumn() {
    items(listTrack){
        TrackCard(it, onClickStartSource = {setSource(it.source)})
    }
}
```

with:

```
@Composable
fun TrackCard(track: Track, onClickStartSource : () -> Unit) {

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(5.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
         onClick = {onClickStartSource},
            //your code
    ){ /* ... */ }
```

Also you can use the [**`combinedClickable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary.html#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).combinedClickable(kotlin.Boolean,%20kotlin.String,%20androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,%20kotlin.String,%20kotlin.Function0,%20kotlin.Function0,%20kotlin.Function0)) modifier to get the different click events:

```
Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(5.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        //.clickable(onClick = onClickStartSource)
        .combinedClickable(
            onLongClick = { /*....*/ },
            onDoubleClick ={ /*....*/ }),
    contentColor = color
)
```

Comment: .combinedClickable  is such a lifesaver ..I'll definitely be using it in my own projects

Comment: @Narendra_Nath @Remo just a final note: `combinedClickable` is currently (`1.0.0-beta05`) marked as `@ExperimentalFoundationApi`

Answer (score 23):

You can add a click event to a Card like this. Put the code you would want to include for the click inside the clickable function

```
Card(
modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp).fillMaxWidth().clickable{ },
        contentColor = Color.Black       
    )
```